# Is there a way to Encrypt my Mongo Atlas connection string with Unity or Mongo?

Tags: c#, mongodb, unity-game-engine, security, encryption

Let's say I have a connection string in Unity C#

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;

public class MongoConnection : MonoBehaviour
{
   private MongoClient client;
   // Connection String Example
   private string connectionString = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>cluster0[...]";

   void Start()
    {
        if (!connected)
        {
            ConnectToMongoDB();
        }
    }

   // Example of a Simple Connection Code
   public bool ConnectToMongoDB()
   {
        client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        database = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
        try
        {
            var result = client.GetDatabase("admin").RunCommand<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("ping", 1));
            Debug.Log("Good connection to Mongo Atlas!");
            connected = true;
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError(e);
            connected = false;
            return false;
        }
   }
}
```

Im not sure if that's accessible or no, so I want to keep it safe. Is there another way to do it or another option to connect to Mongo which is safer? Please help me, it's for a steam game so I want to keep everything as safe as possible.

Comment: Where does `connectionString` exist?

Comment: In the script in charge of the Database actions

Comment: This is why web  calls which interface the db are made.

Comment: If the `connectionSTring` in the _"script in charge of the Database actions"_ is physically located on a user's machine, it can be retrieved with little effort.

Comment: Exactly, so what should I do?

Comment: One way would be to implement what @BugFinder commented on - have a server that interfaces between the user and the database.

Comment: You can enable SSL/TLS certificates to encrypt the connection. The certificate you can download from your Atlas page.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit The game model isn't completely clear, and it seems the OP intended to connect directly from the "user device" to the MongoDB server - I'm not sure.  If so, `connectionString` could be read from object dumps, system calls, memory, etc.  A gamer/hacker could possibly use this to max out his/her scores, or worse.  Although, depending on game design, a hacker might achieve this even with an intermediate server and without `connectionString`.

Comment: Do not allow client to directly connect to the database - this only ends up in a security nightmare and a hacked database. Develop an HTTP API that allows to perform only those DB queries you need. If possible secure it with authentication.